# git init --bare results in fatal: unable to get current working directory: No error when using UNC

Tags: windows, git, init, unc

I created a link from the DOS shell with (I had to run the DOS shell as Administrator)

`C:\Users\Rob> mklink /D MyRepo  \\somewhere\MyRepo`

Next, from MINGW (I use Git For Windows) I got

```
$ ls 
MyRepo@
```

Next, if I do

```
$ cd MyRepo
$ touch A.txt
```

I can see the `A.txt` file in the network location opened in Windows Explorer. That means this mechanism works.
On the other hand, it happens that

```
$ git init --bare 
fatal: unable to get current working directory: No error
```

Any hint?

Comment: What version of git are you using? I find git on Cygwin/MinGW to be finicky sometimes.

Comment: git version 2.8.2.windows.1

Comment: check with latest one, they regularly announce some UNC related fixes

Comment: I updated to git version 2.12.0.windows.1 but it didn't work either. On the other hand, the command has the effect of creating a folder in the remote location, but then it seems it is not able to read it.